# webrtc streaming video only one side

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm trying to make a video chat application based in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

It works well in the same network, 
but when I try other networks have the following problem:

- If i invite other user, only the other user can see the streaming
- If he invites me, only he can see the streaming

I think the problem is in iceservers, 
I'm using [{'url':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]

Any ideas on how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the same article that you mention:

> If UDP fails, ICE tries TCP: first HTTP, then HTTPS. If direct connection fails—in particular, because of enterprise NAT traversal and firewalls—ICE uses an intermediary (relay) TURN server. In other words, ICE will first use STUN with UDP to directly connect peers and, if that fails, will fall back to a TURN relay server.

If I'm not mistaken, you use only STUN server. In this case if direct connection is not possible, and without TURN server, which acts as a relay, it's not possible to establish two-way connection.

Check out this article about how to set up your own TURN server, and about all this STUN and TURN stuff: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem creating my own server STUN/TURN, now is working two-way connection.
Alaershov thank you for your help.