# WebRTC: no video on initiating side

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to implement the process described in [MDN: the WebRTC perfect negotiation pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation), with WebSockets-based signalling to start a two-way video connection.

The snag is: I cannot get the initiating side to receive the video or audio streams. On the receiving side I see both local and remote video, on the initiating side only the local stream.

I have checked the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781261/webrtc-streaming-video-only-one-side) and set up my own STUN/TURN server (CoTurn) but no improvement.

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for the ton of code, but WebRTC seems just made that way.

```
 var peerConnectionConfig = { 'iceServers': [ {'urls': 'turn:my.turn.server:3478', "username": "foo", "credential": "bar" } ] };
 
 let localPeerConnection, remotePeerConnection;
 let localStream;
 let hangupSent = false;
 let isCaller = false;
 
 const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
 const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
 const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
 const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');
 
 // Signaling WebSocket connection
 const signalingSocket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.hostname);
 signalingSocket.addEventListener('message', handleSignalingData);
 
 // Set up user media and create peer connections
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
     video: { facingMode: 'user' },
     audio: true
 }).then(gotLocalMediaStream).catch(handleError);
 
 startButton.addEventListener('click', startCall);
 hangupButton.addEventListener('click', hangUp);
 
 function gotLocalMediaStream(mediaStream) {
     localStream = mediaStream;
     localVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
     localVideo.setAttribute("playsinline", true);
     remoteVideo.setAttribute("playsinline", true);
     
     // Create local peer connection
     localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
     localPeerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', handleConnection);
     localPeerConnection.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', handleConnectionChange);
     
     // Create remote peer connection
     remotePeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
     remotePeerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', handleConnection);
     remotePeerConnection.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', handleConnectionChange);
     remotePeerConnection.addEventListener('track', gotRemoteMediaStream);
     
     // Add tracks to the local peer connection
     mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
         localPeerConnection.addTrack(track, mediaStream);
     });
 }
 
 function startCall() {
     // Create offer and set local description
     isCaller = true;
     localPeerConnection.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1 })
         .then(offer => {
             return localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer)
         })
         .then(() => {
             // Send offer to the remote peer
             signalingSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'offer': localPeerConnection.localDescription }));
         })
         .catch(handleError);
 }
 
 function hangUp() {
     // Send hangup signal
     if (!hangupSent) {
         // Send hangup signal only if it hasn't been sent before
         signalingSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'hangup': true }));
         hangupSent = true; // Set the flag to true after sending the hangup signal
     }
     
     localPeerConnection.close();
     remotePeerConnection.close();
     localPeerConnection = null;
     remotePeerConnection = null;
 }
 
 function handleConnection(event) {
     const peerConnection = event.target;
     const iceCandidate = event.candidate;
     
     if (iceCandidate) {
         const newIceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
         const otherPeer = getOtherPeer(peerConnection);
         // Send ICE candidate to the remote peer
         signalingSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'iceCandidate': newIceCandidate }));
     }
 }
 
 function gotRemoteMediaStream(event) {
     console.log("gotRemoteMediaStream")
     const mediaStream = event.streams[0];
     remoteVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
     // remoteVideo.setAttribute("playsinline", true);
     // localVideo.style.display = 'none';
 }
 
 function handleConnectionChange(event) {
     const peerConnection = event.target;
     console.log(`ICE state change event: ${peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`);
 }
 
 function handleSignalingData(event) {
     const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
     if (data.offer) {
         // this is for the side receiving the call
         if (isCaller) { return }
         isCaller = false
         console.log("got offer")
         remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.offer))
             .then(() => remotePeerConnection.createAnswer())
             .then(answer => remotePeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer))
             .then(() => {
                 signalingSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'answer': remotePeerConnection.localDescription }));
             })
             .catch(e => {
                 console.error("on receiving side")
                 console.error(e.toString())
             });
     } else if (data.answer) {
         // this is for the side initiating the call
         console.log("got answer")
         if (!isCaller) { return }
         // Handle answer from the remote peer
         console.log(data.answer)
         localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer))
             .catch(e => {
                 console.error("on initiating side")
                 console.error(e.toString())
             });
     } else if (data.iceCandidate) {
         // Handle ICE candidate from the remote peer
         localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.iceCandidate))
             .then(() => {
             })
             .catch(e => {
                 console.error("on ice candidate")
                 console.error(isCaller)
                 console.error(e.toString())
             });
     } else if (data.hangup) {
         // Handle hangup signal
         hangUp();
     }
 }
 
 function getOtherPeer(peerConnection) { return (peerConnection === localPeerConnection) ? remotePeerConnection : localPeerConnection }
 
 function handleError(error) { console.error(`Error: ${error}`) }
```

Comment: On the receiving side, have you tried to add the media stream to remotePeerConnection?

Comment: @TheKNVB - the fact that I don't understand the question probably means the answer is no. Could you tell me where in the code would you add that?

Comment: You may try to add the media stream to remotePeerConnection after "signalingSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'answer': remotePeerConnection.localDescription }));"

Comment: @TheKNVB - thanks I'll try asap and report back